# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before and

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm dying I just keep getting this error can someone help me.

[image]

and the second error is the same message but with this code.

```
for (idx=0;idx<childs.length;++idx) {
    if (typeof(obj[childs[idx]]) == 'object' != childs[idx] != "$xml") {
        out += this.dump( obj[childs[idx]], childs[idx], nLevels );
    } else {
        out += sPre + '\t' + childs[idx] + '="' + obj[childs[idx]].toString() + '"\n';
    }
}
```

the error is at the row of the if statement.

Comment: Missing image and links

Comment: sorry about that just added the link.

Comment: @flamespitter Your question has been downvoted because it's concerning one of the fundamentals of AS3, I'm speaking about AS3's operators : the [**logical AND**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#logical_AND) operator is `&&` and not `and`, the [**inequality**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#inequality) one is `!=` and not neither `ne` nor `<>`, for more, take a look [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/operators.html).

Comment: thank you for your arrogance but the problem still persists. ive attached a different image please check it.

Comment: @flamespitter Arrogance !!! I tried just to help you (I didn't even downvote your post). You got the same errors because you've to save your edits and test again (don't forget the 315th line also) ...

Comment: @akmozo look if u didn't mean anything by it then its my fault sorry and thanks for your help

Comment: True arrogance is calling the person trying to help you 'arrogant'.  For shame, flamespitter.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

`if (typeof(obj[childs[idx]]) == 'object' and childs[idx] ne "$xml") {`

"and" is not an operator in as3.  You're looking for `&&`.

"ne" is also not an operator in as3.

In pseudocode, what you're trying to do is:

"If my first variable is an 'object', and my second variable is not equal to "$xml", then do stuff."

You need to use the correct operators for those operations, not random names (from other languages, perhaps?).

Checking the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html) would be a good idea.

Comment: didn't work, is there another thing you can think of?

Comment: As @Brian suggest, look at the documentation and check how to use operators in AS3. You cannot use "ne" operator in AS3.

Comment: @SameerJain Thanks, I've updated my answer based on your comment :D

Comment: ive changed the codes in the question but the error is still there. please check it out.

Comment: Not sure if you really have edited the code in the question (not the image) but it still says "!= childs[idx]" instaed of "&& childs[idx]". It's odd that you have nothing at all at the line 176 though

Comment: Have you published flash after editing. As @Philarmon said, you dont have anything on line 176, what happen if you double click on the error line?

Comment: alright thanks already fixed the problem. just copied it to a new file whatever the problem was its gone now.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `and` as an operator. You must use `&&`. See below

`if(node.nodeType == 1 && node.firstChild.nodeType <> 3)`

However, note that `<>` is not an operator and cannot be used. I'm not sure whether you want greater than or less than so you'll have to fix that.

As for the second error, same issue. You cannot use `and`

`if (typeof(obj[childs[idx]]) == 'object' && childs[idx] ne "$xml")`

Also note again that `ne` is not a valid operator either and must be fixed

Comment: i tried that it didnt work check the new image in the question.

Comment: @flamespitter See the scroll bar? It's tiny. Scroll all the way to the right and make sure there's nothing else on line 176. As for the next error, `if (typeof(obj[childs[idx]]) == 'object' != childs[idx] != "$xml")` should be `if (typeof(obj[childs[idx]]) == 'object' && childs[idx] != "$xml")`

Comment: @flamespitter Delete the entire line anyways. Report back if it still gives the error

Comment: alright thanks already fixed the problem. just copied it to a new file whatever the problem was its gone now.

Comment: It's not every day you get programming advice from Taylor Swift!  Truly, now I've seen everything.